# What does word Кухонні mean in this context?

Tags: значення-слів

What does the term  mean in the context of this sentence?

> У нас, скажімо так… Не «кухонні» ми.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quote appears to be from the book written by Євгенія Подобна, ["Дівчата зрізають коси: Книга спогадів / російсько–українська війна"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?isbn=6177420397). A more complete quote would be (highlight mine):

> На моє рішення чоловік відреагував нормально, ми ж разом поїхали. Він знав, що я його самого не відпущу, і знав, що він мене не відпустить саму. Я теж спортсменка, доволі активна людина, ми націоналісти обидва, радикального такого духовного покликання. У нас, скажімо так… **Не «кухонні» ми.** І стало одразу зрозуміло, що **ми не будемо сидіти і лиш увечері за чаєм обговорювати** ситуацію в Україні.

The speaker apparently tries to pick the right words, which makes their speech pretty much disorganized and incoherent, which makes their sentences end abruptly.

But from the entire quote, we may conclude that *кухонні* is a reference to people who only speak out on their kitchens, in the comfort of being among their most trusted family members, and who never try to organize themselves or actively resist.

The speaker says that, on the contrary, they are not of that kind, and that they *will* actively resist the invasion by joining a volunteers' squadron.

There are several similar phrases:

- [*кухонні експерти*](https://life.pravda.com.ua/columns/2019/04/7/236453/) — kitchen experts;
- *диванні війська* — [armchair warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armchair_warrior), and so on;

---

From the comments:

> To what extent is the term used in common language and how much is the creation of speaker, that wants to reflect on the gravity of the situation[?]

Frankly speaking, I have never heard this term as a bare adjective. I'm aware about the use of adjective+noun pairs, mentioned in the last section of my answer. It could be a localized term as well.

Comment: Hello bytebuster. Wau. Thank you very much for your comment and the interpretation of the word in the context of the situation. I could put in a longer fragment of the book"Дівчата зривають коси", but I thought it was enough. In this context, the question arises. To what extent is the term used in common language and how much is the creation of  speaker,  that wants to reflect on the gravity of the situation.

Comment: You're welcome. Frankly speaking, I have never heard this term *as a bare adjective*. I'm aware about the use of adjective+noun pairs, mentioned in the last section of my answer. It could be a localized term as well.

Comment: Hello bytebuster. Thank you very much for your reply. With best regards Jakuro